# Query optimization on text field

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, innodb

I am trying to optimize mysql query by setting index on agent column but it seems my index is not working.
Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Test` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `country_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `agent` TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_general_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB

alter table test add index index_for_agent (agent(767));

explain select * from test cu WHERE cu.agent REGEXP 'bot|Spider|SiteExpl|crawler'
```

[image]

how can i optimize my query

Comment: Did you try using `LIKE` instead? `explain select * from test cu WHERE cu.agent like '%bot%'OR cu.agent like '%Spider%' OR cu.agent like '%SiteExpl%' OR cu.agent like '%crawler%'`

Comment: yes i did but same result

Answer (score 0):

If `agent` takes on a value and *only one value*, then use `in`:

```
select *
from test cu
WHERE cu.agent in ('bot', 'Spider', 'SiteExpl', 'crawler')
```

Then an index on `test(agent)` will be quite efficient.

If agent takes on *multiple* values, then change the data structure, so you have another table, say `test_agent` that has one row per value.  Then the above will work.

If the agents have leading matches, so "bot" should match "bottomless pit", the use multiple statements with `like` and `union all`:

```
select *
from test cu
where cu.agent like 'bot%'
union all
select *
from test cu
where cu.agent like 'spider%'
. . .
```

Along with the index on the field.

If you are looking for full words, then use a full text index.  Note that you will need to change the minimum word length parameter, because the default is 4 and it will not index "bot".

If you need to search for random strings in the field, then I've run out of ideas to improve performance.

Comment: If you truly want to look for string starting as a *random starting position*, then it is typical that a tablescan would give you better performance than using the index. Is there some reason you want to use the index?

Comment: @DariusX. . . . I don't think the OP particularly cares about using an index per se.  I think the OP just wants to speed the query.

Comment: i am new to sql and i read that index can make query faster, but if there are other ways then i am looking forward